# psql --(record|field)-separator NUL

Tags: bash, postgresql, nul

Is there some way to make `psql` separate the fields and records by `\0`, aka NUL? It's the only way to be able to pass *arbitrary* data to Bash scripts.

Based on [Matthew Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857265/psql-recordfield-separator-nul/6867253#6867253)'s answer, I would expect this to print more that `1` on a newly initialized database:

```
declare -i count=0
echo "\pset recordsep '\000'
\f '\000'
select typname from pg_type" | \
sudo -iu postgres psql --no-align --quiet --tuples-only -d dbname -U username | while IFS= read -r -d ''
do
    #echo "$REPLY"
    let count++
done
if [ -n "$REPLY" ]
then
    #echo "$REPLY"
    let count++
fi
echo $count
```

**Workaround**: Iff the `SELECT` results are unique, you can use this workaround to handle one at a time:

```
next_record() {
    psql --no-align --quiet --tuples-only -d dbname -U username <<SQL
SELECT colname
  FROM tablename
 WHERE colname > '${1}'
 ORDER BY colname
 LIMIT 1
SQL
}

last_col=
while true
do
    colx="$(next_record "$last_col"; printf x)"
    if [ "$colx" = x ]
    then
        exit
    fi
    col="${colx%$'\nx'}" # The extra \n character is from psql

    # Do your thing here

    col_escaped="${col//"'"/''}" # Double single quotes
    col_escaped="${col_escaped//\\/\\\\}" # Double backslashes
    last_col="$col_escaped"
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported.  psql uses C print functions to print out the result tables, and printing a zero byte just doesn't work there.

**Update**: This is now supported in PostgreSQL 9.2-to-be ([git](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=169c8a911260bd5a8b6910c458afa57a1ae29627)).

Comment: +1 for the brutal truth. It's too bad they haven't figured out how to print NUL characters in C - It's supported by `sed`, `grep`, `find` `printf` and many more.

Comment: Well, "they" = me, to some degree.  It wouldn't be hard to implement if a broad enough use case were presented.  I'll make a note about it.

Comment: That would be the best thing ever - Iff text fields cannot contain null fields, and I'm selecting a known number of them, I can parse *any* values without worrying about garbage data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
psql --field-separator '\000' --no-align -c '<your query>'
```

Edit: Maybe not.   However, it appear to work in psql using these commands:

```
\f '\000'
\a
```

Comment: This ends up setting the field separator to an empty string, not a zero byte, as was requested.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of `psql` [support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-psql.html) the `--field-separator-zero` flag.